# Simple 32bit processors

Tags: microprocessor

I like playing with simple processors. They are easy to use and there isn't a huge learning curve. I've played with the 6502, Z80, W65C816. But they are 8/16 bit. Is there a 32bit processor out there similar to these?

Comment: Sure, and everything it turns up are ARMs and other complex processors. I was hoping someone knew of a *simple* processors similar to the ones mentioned.

Comment: There is nothing that complex about ARM. If you want to learn something useful, go with it.

Comment: In principle a 32-bit RISC architecture can be extremely simple, but in practice real systems, especially those optimized to be small and efficient like the smaller ARM's, often grow complexity.  C programmers may not have to deal with this too much, but if you actually look at the machine code, there's a lot to puzzle out.

Comment: Pic32s are quite simple to use.

Comment: Sounds like you want to have a look at the PicoRV32, a really minimal implementation of the 32 bit RISC-V ISA

Comment: M68K (now Coldfire)? One of the RISCs or MIPS architectures? What exactly do you mean by "simple"?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, some 32 bit processors are much simpler to use than the 8 bit fossils. For example in Cortex-M:

- No "special" registers, like the result of an addition can only go into register A, or segregated data/address registers or the like. You get a set of 32 bit registers which all have exactly equal abilities. Less rules to remember. Compilers love this.
- No head-banging segmented addressing modes. Want to read a word from memory? Well, just read it.
- No dumb limits like "Oh man you want to multiply two 32 bit numbers that's gonna take a whole bunch of instructions!" Nope, just MUL. (Note: some Cortex-M0 cores have the 1-cycle multiplier, the cheapo ones have the slow one, everything above Cortex-M3 is basically a powerhouse, think like a Pentium Pro from the good old days, without any of the crusty x86 retrocompatiblity).
- DIV instruction (not available on Cortex-M0 though)
- No special instructions for IO. Everything is memory-mapped. Very simple to use.
- 32 bit timers in large quantity.
- NVIC interrupt controller is a work of art.

The only thing complex about the small ARMs is that there are less tutorials available for beginners, but if you search them, you will find them.

Also, the manufacturers usually provide huge libraries of useful code. If you want to use them, you'll have to learn how. You're not forced to use them, though.

Get a STM32 or LPC dev board. It takes a bit of effort adjusting to the new toolchain if you're used to 8 bit, but after half a day you'll be up to speed.

Comment: These may not seem to complex if you are programming in C.  But trying to write the compact *thumb* code (which is all the Cortex-M series runs) directly can indeed be a bit complicated when you look at constant synthesis and things like that.  This is substantially more complex than a clean "academic" RISC architecture.

Comment: Sure, but why would you want to do that? Compilers produce excellent code, and the asm is very readable for debugging purposes.

Comment: If complexity were only going to be hidden behind a compiler, there wouldn't be much point in seeking a "simple" MCU rather than simply one that is cheap, power efficient, or whatever.

Comment: Well, I think being able to read the asm produced by the compiler helps immensely in the "having some idea about what you're doing" bit. IMO this is quite important. So ARM's readable asm is a plus. As far as writing asm, it's been a long time, but my favorite still would be the 68k series. Very well organized and straightforward instruction set, but of course it is a bit of a fossil these days.